# best way to manage filters with a custom style

Tags: android, android-layout, button, material-design, android-chips

I work on an Android app and I need to implement filters based on the app design guidelines.

There are 2 kinds of filters:

- with an icon
- without an icon

The filter can be selected/unselected (or checked/unchecked)

Each case can be visible here:

[image: Filters styles]

There filters will be displayed through a `GridView` by 3 columns on several lines.

***I would like to know which native control is more appropriate to achieve this?***

I've tried to use [Chip](https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips), which has a `checked` parameter, but it seems not possible to change the `chipIcon` position.

I've also tried tried the [Button](https://material.io/components/buttons), which allows to change the icon position with `app:iconGravity`,  but there is no `checked` parameter.

I've also seen [ToggleButtons](https://material.io/components/buttons#toggle-button) but it requires to use `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`, whereas I need to display each filter trough the `GridView`.

***So do I need to create a custom control to achieve this?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally achieved this with a `MaterialButton` and the `android:checkable` property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CheackableCell"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_carwash"
    app:iconGravity="textTop"
    app:iconPadding="12dp"
    tools:text="Car Wash"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:checkable="true"/>
```

It's very close to solution given by Cheticamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ToggleButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton) with a top drawable as follows:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:checked="false"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/car"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableTint="@drawable/icon_text_colors"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/icon_text_colors"
    android:textOff="Car wash"
    android:textOn="Car wash"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

where *background_selector.xml* is

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
</selector>
```

and *icon_text_colors.xml* looks like this:

```
<selector>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

The unchecked state looks like this:

[image]

while the checked state looks like this:

[image]

For the button without the icon, you simply would not specify a drawable for the top.

These are not the colors you want, but this is the idea.